# How to find out the name of application that just flashed and dissapeared

Tags: windows

So every so often a cmd.exe like window would flash for a moment and then disappear. But I'm never able to see exactly what it did. Any way I can find out?

Comment: I would suggest you check your PC for malware first. Probably you can figure out what's causing this via something like Process Monitor, after filtering out only events related to the cmd.exe process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to log the activity in your system